# How to compare fields of oldMap and newMap?

Tags: trigger, helper, trigger-oldmap

I have a trigger helper with this method:

```
public void changeObjects(Map<Id, Cleaning__c> oldObjectsMap, Map<Id, Cleaning__c> newObjectsMap)
```

But it should make changes only if `FieldName__c` is changed. How can I get Id for each record here to compare the values?

```
if(oldObjectsMap.get(someIdIsHere).FieldName__c != (newObjectsMap.get(someIdIsHere).FieldName__c){
    //our code logic
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over either `key` or `value` of the `Trigger.newMap` or `Trigger.oldMap` and in the iteration, you will get the `Id` of each record.

When iterating over the `key` using [`keyset()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) method of either of the maps that you have, you will get the `Id` in each iteration.

```
for(Id recordId : newObjectsMap.keyset()){
    if(oldObjectsMap.get(recordId).FieldName__c != (newObjectsMap.get(recordId).FieldName__c){
        //your code logic
    }
}
```

Similarly, if needed, you can iterate over `values` as well using the [`values()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) method, but in that case, you will have to access the `Id` from the `sObject` either using Dot notation or using the `get` method of [`sObject`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of performance, you should use Trigger.old and Trigger.new instead of Trigger.oldMap and/or Trigger.newMap. You'll also get better performance by caching objects. Here's what a typical loop looks like in my triggers:

```
for(Integer i = 0, s = Trigger.new.size(); i < s; i++) {
  sObject oldRecord = Trigger.old[i], newRecord = Trigger.new[i];
  // do logic here //
}
```

This design minimizes the number of array/map accesses and method calls, and generally has the best performance characteristics, important for bulk data loads.

Comment: Yes, but I need a Map for another part of code. So, I used a Map instead of a list

Comment: @DanDan both maps and lists are tools to be used appropriately. You wouldn't want to use a screwdriver when you need a hammer, nor a hammer when you need a screwdriver. I'm not saying "never use maps", just "don't use maps for this purpose."